# DIV expanding to next DIV

Tags: html, web, width

I have two divs under menu of site: content and right-content.Right content is sidebar which is fixed to the right side of screen,and he has a wiht 200px.Content is div for content of site and I want him to start on the left side of the screen and to stop when it reaches the right-content.Some suggestions?

HTML code of DIVs:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
<div id="rightcontent">
bla vlaaa
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
#content {
float:left;
position:absolute;
background-color:#ffffff;
height:500px;
}

#rightcontent {
margin-top:5px;
border:1px solid;
border-color:#ffffff;
border-radius:5px;
float:right;
position:relative;
background-color:#D4D3D0;
width:300px;
height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a wrapping div for the content, and padding or margins to do this.  For example, the style sheet could look something like this:

```
.div-content-wrapper { 
    width: 100%;
}
.div-content { 
    margin-right: 200px; 
}
.div-rightsidebar { 
    width: 200px; 
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
}
```

And the html would look like this:

```
<div class="div-content-wrapper">
    <div class="div-content">
        <h1> This content will not go further than 200px from the right side</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="div-rightsidebar">
        <h4>Right bar content</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

The right sidebar can go inside or outside of the wrapper, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Does not work, I put width 100% but the margin-right:300px; is not performing its function, the content is 100% and going below the right-content.

Comment: If you copy the code exactly how it is displayed above it works. Check it out on jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/FfjWS/](http://jsfiddle.net/FfjWS/). I added some background color and height to help make it more visible.  If it still isn't working, what browser are you using?